# Auto reloading properties file after updating it in Spring. How to achieve this?

Tags: spring, properties-file

Instead of restarting the sever every time i make any change i want my properties file to be auto refreshed. My properties file in the src/main/resources

Comment: Auto build? did yo try that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Actuator, basically you put your configuration beans inside a refresh scope :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    @RefreshScope
    class ExampleController {

        @Value("${foo.bar}")
        private String value;

        @RequestMapping
        public String sayValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you change the configuration. you call the refresh endpoint for the actuator.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/refresh
```